# Root and/or flash ROM on Haier Haipad 8.0 (PAD821)

Tags: rooting, custom-roms

I'm trying to root my haipad but none of the methods I found over the internet works.
Here the PAD821 features:

```
Basic parameters

Time to market: February 2013
Product positioning: Entertainment Tablet PC
Operating system: Android4.1
CPU/GPU Processor architecture: ARM architecture
Processor model: ARM Cortex-A9
Processor Main Frequency: 1.5GHz
Processors core: Dual core

Storage device
System memory: 1GB
Storage capacity: 8GB
Storage media: Flash Flash disk
Storage expansion: supports Micro SD (TF) card, maximum support 32GB

Display
Screen size: 8 inches
Screen resolution: 1024x768
Screen description: Capacitive touch screen, Multi-point touch screen
Pointing device: touch screen
Screen characteristics: Five-point touch screen,The TFT screen,LED backlight
Language support: supports many languages
Network connection: WiFi support
Network mode: 3G module reserved ports
Bluetooth: Bluetooth 4

Multimedia features
Sound system: Double stereo speakers,Built-in microphone
Video playback: support playback of 720P vide
Camera: dual camera (front: 300,000 pixels, rear: 2 million pixels)
Video recording: support for recording 720P video
Flash features: supports Flash

Format support
Audio format: supports MP3 format
Video formats: supports MP4 format
Picture formats: support JPEG,BMP,GIF,format
Text formatting: supports TXT format
Buttons/interfaces: Data interface Micro-USB
Audio interface: 3.5mm earphone interface
Other interface: power interface,memory card interface
Function keys: switch button, volume buttons

Power parameter
Battery type: Lithium battery,4400mAh
Life time: depending on the using environment, at a specific time
Power adapter: DC (5V, 2A) adaptive AC power supply
Function parameters: Built-in induction The intelligent gravity sensor
Basic applications: Baidu input method,The ES file browser,PPTV,AppChina,WPS

Appearance parameters
Product size: 204.37x155.42x9.5mm
weight: 432g 
Casing material: composite materials
Casing color: silver
```

Is there someone who knows a ROM compatible with such a device? Otherwise: is there a way to root it? Which version of the recovery (CWM or TWRP) can I install?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search leads me to believe that the device in question is extremely osbscure. Rooting it is **probably possible, but almost definitely won't be easy**. I was unable to find any methods for rooting it.

A custom ROM is **almost entirely out of the question**. I don't think there are any custom ROMs compatible with the device at all.

Additionally, **I don't think there are any custom recovery options** available to you at all.

I would say that unless you are very experienced with treading where none have tread before for the device - gaining root manually, hacking, compiling kernels, compiling ROMs for the device - you're more or less out of luck.

Anyone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried to search for this device on http://forum.xda-developers.com? They should have got the ROM and the ROOTing method for you.

**Note:** Never try to ROOT or install a ROM from someone you don't trust! Again never root the device when its still in use, because Rooting the device would remove the warranty of its! You might brick your device too.

You can try to search for the ROM by the name. Secondly I know the good rooting software, search for Bin4ry root! They will root you device, you can follow steps! hehehe, you must see the Note I provided before continuing the process.

By that software, you can first Root the device. Then check for the CWM support for your device on their site. Or you can Google it to find the best solution for that phone. After installing the CWM, you can easily install a ROM, but again, becarefull while installing the ROM, you might brick the phone.

Good luck, Cheers!

Comment: It's unlikely that XDA Developers will have anything for a this device. Doing some googling leads me to believe that it's an extremely uncommon tablet to begin with, rooting and getting a ROM will most likely be a huge ordeal.

Comment: Additionally, while it's true that the risk of bricking most devices is low, it's clearly not something to understate - especially for obscure devices like this! And your explanation of why he shouldn't worry is unclear and seems inaccurate.

Comment: Ok, so you downvoted me, because I was helping the dude you had to way to go? :/ and so that your answer should lead the question? Wow! :) Nice mentality brother.

Comment: I'd be happy to remove the downvote if it's edited. This isn't about competition, but because the answer isn't quite right. And it's also dangerous to tell someone "don't worry" when they're rooting an unknown device with untested methods.

Comment: I am having a phone made by `Qmobile` there was no way to root it. I did! I don't want kudos for that but still. If you're so much afraid, then why are you trying to root it? Doesn't make sense and what else do you want me to add here, the stuff that you have posted? :/

Comment: The thing is I *literally* can't remove the downvote unless you edit *something*. =(. If you feel like my answer is just wrong, then feel free to downvote it.

Comment: Well dotVezz, I wasn't here to downvote anyone, unless he is posting some rubbish stuff. You have nothing rubbish, so why should I? And edit something eh? Ok! wait

Comment: There, i removed the `just for info` thing!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10875/discussion-between-dotvezz-and-afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan)

Comment: hehe the thing that you having issue with! :D

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your suggestions. Thanks to Afzaal: I asked on this forum because I googled a lot and I couldn't find anything. My last chance was to understand if such a device was a clone of a well known tablet and I could use ROMs and recovery for that one. Thanks also to dotVezz: your criticism is correct and I agree that the answer can be misleading for some readers. But, this is not my case ;-)